# Picture from camera not showing up in second activity

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, imageview

I feel sorry to come and ask people for help, but I've been stuck with this problem for a while and it's driving me mad.

I'm trying to take a button from MainActivity where it puts you into the camera and takes a picture. It then takes you to the next Activity where there is a preview of the very same image. But whenever I arrive to the next activity the image doesn't show up, just a placeholder. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something in the code?

I've been looking around and tried to use Uri, but apparently it's not permitted anymore as you need to give specific permissions for the action, so FileProvider is recommended, but honestly It's a little bit too hard for a beginner like me. I tried and failed for hours.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int CAPTURE_REQUEST;
Button button;
Bitmap thumbnail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_REQUEST);
        }

    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            sendImage();
        }
    }
}


private void sendImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("image", thumbnail);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

NextActivity

```
public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("image");
        if (image != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: In your function sendImage(), does it contain the correct image?

Comment: I would believe so. But I have do admit, Android Studies tells me that when I declare Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) yada yada, it is never used anywhere else even though I use it in sendImage()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change onActivityResult to

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_REQUEST) {
        thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        sendImage();
    }
}
```

You are overriding your global variable with the local declaration.